# How to Add images to DataGridView (to specific column per each row) Dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Using C# and Webforms, the code below:

```
DataGridViewImageColumn img = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
string path = "path" + file;
Image image = Image.FromFile(path);
img.Image = image;
DataGridView.Columns.Add(img);
img.HeaderText = "Picture";
img.Name = "picture";
```

My problem is the next one. This code is not working... DataGridview is not showing the image.
When I debugged this code, the path is correct, and I load the Image properly in img element. Even more, when I´m using several images, the DataGridView is showing the same number of columns that I´m adding. But not any image at all is displayed, I only can see the typical white square within red cross...

What is the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add the image(s) to the `Cells` like this:

```
dataGridView1[yourColumn, yourRow].Value = Image.FromFile(path);
```

Of course you can use any other image source.. This way you can load **different** images to each `Row`..

**Note**: If you really only want to add the **same** image to each `Row` you can do that with your code, **but** you need to add **real** rows.

It will **not** show in the last row, when `AllowUserToAddRows` is on but will show on all other  rows you add..

Comment: Thanks TaW for your quickly answer...

When I try that, I get the string "System.Drawing.Bitmap" in the column...
This is the code:
int i = 0;
foreach (var url in queryLINQ.First().arrayURLs)
            {
                DataGridView.Rows.Add();
                
                string path = "E:/WorkSpaces/MVS/Proyect" + url;
                DataGridView[0, i].Value = Image.FromFile(path);
                i++;
            }

Any idea?

Comment: That means that your columIndex is wrong! Note that the order is [column, row] not the other way round!! Are you sure the imageColumn is the first one? Or that you have not yet added the imageColumn..

Comment: There is only one column... That one... So it should be... isn´t?

Comment: Hm, as it works fine here I don't know.. If I set the value to a non-ImageColumn value I get the same error.

Comment: Bah... You´re right. Dumb... :S. I forgot to add the column as a Imagecolum... :P... Thanks a lot TaW...

Well... If I can abuse of your patiente... How can I set the height of the column?

Comment: You can only set the height of the whole row and also only do so on a per-row basis; since you are using a loop anyway you can do it right there..: `dataGridView1.Rows[row].Height = ((Bitmap)(dataGridView1[col, row].FormattedValue)).Height;`

Comment: Done... Sorry, quite lazy me... How Can I rate your answer?

Comment: Not yet as that takes 15rep on your side. But you can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it (which gets you 2rep) ..and once you got 15rep points you may come back up upvote those folks that have helped you so far..

Comment: Did it... I´ll come back for rate your answer when I get 15 points. Thanks Taw!!! Regards...

Answer (score 1):

Just Sharing the final code solution was by @TaW
Someone asked me for it:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            codigo = int.Parse(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());

            Piso formPiso = new Piso();

            var consultaPisoAlquiler = from piso in contexto.pisosAlquiler
                                       where piso.codigo == codigo
                                       select new
                                       {
                                           fotos = piso.fotos.Split(','),
                                           zona = piso.zona,
                                           mm = piso.mm,
                                           descripcion = piso.descripcion,
                                           precio = piso.precio,
                                           estado = piso.estado
                                       };

            formPiso.txtCodigo.Text = codigo.ToString();
            formPiso.txtDescripcion.Text = consultaPisoAlquiler.First().descripcion.ToString();
            formPiso.txtEstado.Text = consultaPisoAlquiler.First().estado.ToString();
            formPiso.txtMm.Text = consultaPisoAlquiler.First().mm.ToString();
            formPiso.txtPrecio.Text = consultaPisoAlquiler.First().precio.ToString();
            formPiso.txtZona.Text = consultaPisoAlquiler.First().zona.ToString();

            formPiso.DGVPisoFotos.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            formPiso.DGVPisoFotos.Columns.Clear();
            DataGridViewImageColumn img = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
            img.Width = 230;
            img.HeaderText = "Fotos";
            formPiso.DGVPisoFotos.Columns.Add(img);
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var foto in consultaPisoAlquiler.First().fotos)
            {
                formPiso.DGVPisoFotos.Rows.Add();
                string path = "E:/WorkSpaces/MVS/ProyectoJoseph/" + foto;
                Bitmap image = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(path);
                Bitmap imageRS = new Bitmap(image, new Size(230, 230));
                formPiso.DGVPisoFotos[0, i].Value = imageRS;
                formPiso.DGVPisoFotos.Rows[i].Height = 230;
                i++;
            }

            formPiso.ShowDialog();
}
```